# Copy the values of a sequence from one Oracle database to another

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to copy the current values of sequences in a schema to another database? The sequences have already been created in both databases. This is in Oracle.

Edit:

Based on the help below, once the database link is set up, this script will make sure that the target database sequence values are greater than or equal to the source database values. The motivation for this is so that we don't get primary key errors after copying data, so the fact that the target numbers are not exact is no problem.

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  CURSOR GetCursorsToSync
  is
  SELECT a.sequence_name, a.last_number last_number_a, b.last_number last_number_b
  FROM user_sequences@SOURCE_DB a, user_sequences b
  where a.sequence_name = b.sequence_name
  and a.last_number != b.last_number;

  type CursorsTableType is table of GetCursorsToSync%rowtype index by pls_integer;  
  CursorsTable  CursorsTableType;
  i             pls_integer;

  PROCEDURE reset_sequence(
      sequence_name IN VARCHAR2,
      source_value  IN NUMBER,
      target_value  IN NUMBER )
  IS
    l_sql varchar2(4000);
    l_temp number(30);
  BEGIN
    IF source_value <= target_value THEN
      RETURN;
    END IF;

    dbms_output.put_line(sequence_name || ' ' || source_value || ' ' || target_value);
    l_sql := 'alter sequence '|| sequence_name || ' increment by '||to_char(source_value-target_value);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
    EXECUTE immediate l_sql;
    l_sql := 'SELECT '|| sequence_name || '.nextval FROM dual';
    dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
    EXECUTE immediate l_sql into l_temp;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_temp);
    l_sql := 'alter sequence '|| sequence_name || ' increment by 1';
    dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
    EXECUTE immediate l_sql;
    COMMIT;
  END reset_sequence;
BEGIN
  open GetCursorsToSync;
  fetch GetCursorsToSync bulk collect into CursorsTable;
  close GetCursorsToSync;
  commit;

  i := CursorsTable.first;
  while i is not null loop
    reset_sequence(CursorsTable(i).sequence_name,
      CursorsTable(i).last_number_a,CursorsTable(i).last_number_b);
    i := CursorsTable.next(i);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: It might be worth thinking about using the db_link and the sequences in the target db in your source db processes, rather than having the same sequences in both databases.

Comment: This is basically seeding data from one database into another, so I don't want them to be connected after this process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of UltraCommits statements and a database link, in addition to a stored procedure that you can schedule to automatically run, would serve you well.

```
--drop create db_link
DROP DATABASE LINK SOURCE_DB;

CREATE DATABASE LINK "SOURCE_DB"
  CONNECT TO USER IDENTIFIED BY password USING 'SOURCE_DB';

 --drop create sequences 
  DROP sequence target_seq;
CREATE sequence target_seq start with 6;

  --the next two lines run in source db
  DROP sequence source_seq;
CREATE sequence source_seq start with 6000;

--take a look at the sequences to get an idea of what to expect
SELECT source_schema.source_seq.nextval@SOURCE_DB source_seq,
  target_seq.nextval target_seq
FROM dual; 

--create procedure to reset target sequence that you can schedule to automatically run
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE reset_sequence
AS
  l_source_sequence pls_integer;
  l_target_sequence pls_integer;
  l_sql VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT source_schema.source_seq.nextval@SOURCE_DB,
    target_seq.nextval
  INTO l_source_sequence,
    l_target_sequence
  FROM dual;
  l_sql := 'alter sequence target_seq increment by '||to_number(l_source_sequence-l_target_sequence);
  EXECUTE immediate l_sql;
  SELECT target_seq.nextval INTO l_target_sequence FROM dual;
  l_sql := 'alter sequence target_seq increment by 1';
  EXECUTE immediate l_sql;
  COMMIT;
END reset_sequence;
/

--execute procedure to test it out
EXECUTE reset_sequence;

--review results; should be the same
SELECT source_schema.source_seq.nextval@SOURCE_DB, target_seq.nextval FROM dual;
```

Comment: That looks good, thanks. Then I guess I can wrap it up in a procedure to get all the sequences in my schema and transfer them.

Comment: I edited my question to incorporate my procedure based on your suggestion. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the following error while attempting to execute a script based on the one provided by Mr. Reynold:

**ORA-04013: number to CACHE must be less than one cycle.**

Cause: number to CACHE given is larger than values in a cycle.
Action: enlarge the cycle, or cache fewer values.

This error is encountered if the current *nextval* is too large to allow for the specified number of values to be cached in the current cycle. Accordingly, I have included an updated version of his script in which the target sequence is first altered with the "NOCACHE" option, then the cache is restored to it's original value after the target *nextval* has been updated. In my example the db-link and alias "PD" refers to the source database and "QA" refers to the target database.

I hope this is as helpful to someone else as the previous solution was to me.

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
   CURSOR GetCursorsToSync IS
   SELECT pd.sequence_name, pd.last_number last_number_pd,
          qa.last_number last_number_qa, qa.cache_size
     FROM user_sequences@PD pd
     JOIN user_sequences qa
       on qa.sequence_name = pd.sequence_name
    WHERE qa.last_number != pd.last_number;

   TYPE CursorsTableType IS
   TABLE OF GetCursorsToSync%ROWTYPE INDEX BY pls_integer;  
      CursorsTable  CursorsTableType;
      i             pls_integer;

   PROCEDURE Reset_Sequence(
      sequence_name IN VARCHAR2,
      source_value  IN NUMBER,
      target_value  IN NUMBER,
      cache_size    IN NUMBER)
   IS
      l_sql    VARCHAR2(4000);
      l_temp   NUMBER(30);
   BEGIN
      IF source_value <= target_value THEN
         RETURN;
      END IF;

      dbms_output.put_line(sequence_name || ' ' || source_value || ' ' || target_value);
      IF cache_size > 0 THEN
         l_sql := 'alter sequence '|| sequence_name || ' nocache';
         dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
      END IF;

      l_sql := 'alter sequence '|| sequence_name || ' increment by ' || TO_CHAR(source_value-target_value);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;

      l_sql := 'SELECT ' || sequence_name || '.nextval FROM dual';
      dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql INTO l_temp;

      dbms_output.put_line(l_temp);

      l_sql := 'alter sequence ' || sequence_name || ' increment by 1';
      dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;

      IF cache_size > 0 THEN
         l_sql := 'alter sequence '|| sequence_name || ' cache ' || TO_CHAR(cache_size);
         dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
      END IF;

      COMMIT;
   END Reset_Sequence;

BEGIN
   OPEN GetCursorsToSync;
   FETCH GetCursorsToSync BULK COLLECT INTO CursorsTable;
   CLOSE GetCursorsToSync;
   COMMIT;

   i := CursorsTable.FIRST;
   WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
      Reset_Sequence(CursorsTable(i).sequence_name, CursorsTable(i).last_number_pd,
         CursorsTable(i).last_number_qa, CursorsTable(i).cache_size);
      i := CursorsTable.NEXT(i);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--
-- Procedure to replicate the value of sequences from source to destination schema
--
-- The database link name must be PROD
--
-- SQL> CREATE DATABASE LINK PROD CONNECT TO ...
--
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RESET_SEQUENCES
AS
    CURSOR CSEQUENCES
    IS
    SELECT   SEQUENCE_NAME
    FROM     USER_SEQUENCES@PROD;

    L_SEQUENCE_NAME     USER_SEQUENCES.SEQUENCE_NAME%TYPE;
    L_SRC_SEQ_VALUE     USER_SEQUENCES.MAX_VALUE%TYPE;
    L_DST_SEQ_VALUE     USER_SEQUENCES.MAX_VALUE%TYPE;

    L_SQL VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN

    OPEN CSEQUENCES;

    LOOP

        FETCH CSEQUENCES INTO L_SEQUENCE_NAME;
        EXIT WHEN CSEQUENCES%NOTFOUND;
        --
        -- Select sequence value from source schema
        --
        L_SQL := 'SELECT '|| L_SEQUENCE_NAME ||'.NEXTVAL@PROD FROM DUAL';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_SQL INTO L_SRC_SEQ_VALUE;
        --
        -- Select sequence value from destination schema
        --
        L_SQL := 'SELECT '|| L_SEQUENCE_NAME ||'.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_SQL INTO L_DST_SEQ_VALUE;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SEQUENCE_NAME: '||L_SEQUENCE_NAME);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('::BEFORE => SRC VALUE: '||L_SRC_SEQ_VALUE||' DST VALUE: '||L_DST_SEQ_VALUE);

        --
        -- Synchronize sequences value, only if necessary
        --
        IF L_SRC_SEQ_VALUE > L_DST_SEQ_VALUE THEN
            --
            -- Alter increment by to diference between L_SRC_SEQ_VALUE and L_DST_SEQ_VALUE
            --
            L_SQL := 'ALTER SEQUENCE '|| L_SEQUENCE_NAME ||' INCREMENT BY '||TO_CHAR(L_SRC_SEQ_VALUE-L_DST_SEQ_VALUE);

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_SQL;
            --
            -- Select sequence value
            --
            L_SQL := 'SELECT '|| L_SEQUENCE_NAME ||'.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_SQL INTO L_DST_SEQ_VALUE;
            --
            -- Alter increment by back to 1
            --
            L_SQL := 'ALTER SEQUENCE '|| L_SEQUENCE_NAME ||' INCREMENT BY 1';

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_SQL;

        END IF;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('::AFTER  => SRC VALUE: '||L_SRC_SEQ_VALUE||' DST VALUE: '||L_DST_SEQ_VALUE);

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE CSEQUENCES;

END RESET_SEQUENCES;
/

--
-- EXECUTE RESET_SEQUENCES PROCEDURE AND BE HAPPY!
--
SQL> EXEC RESET_SEQUENCES
```

Answer (score 0):

Question: How do we set the LASTVALUE value in an Oracle Sequence?
Answer: You can change the LASTVALUE for an Oracle sequence, by executing an ALTER
SEQUENCE command.
For example, if the last value used by the Oracle sequence was 100 and you would like to reset the sequence to serve 225 as the next value. You would execute the following commands.

```
alter sequence seq_name increment by 224;
select seq_name.nextval from dual;
alter sequence seq_name increment by 1;
```

Now, the next value to be served by the sequence will be 225.

Comment: Yes, but that is a manual process for each sequence, and what i really want is some automated way of doing it.

Comment: Can we suppose the existence of a database link between databases?